# É possível migrar os pontos e medalhas do Stackoverflow.com?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Se no Stackoverflow.com eu já estou com uma pontuação mais elevada, por que em meu próprio idioma eu devo começar do zero? Isso desmotiva a colaboração já que não é possível votar ou mesmo adicionar respostas.

Comment: Olá, essa pergunta deveria estar no Meta, mas respondendo ela, apesar de ter o mesmo nome, são redes distintas, logo cada uma deve ter sua própria 'moeda'.

Comment: Quando você chegar aos 200 pontos de reputação em qualquer site da rede você terá 100 pontos extras para todos os sites em que você participar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ler "**StackOverflow Original**" doeu na alma

Comment: @jbueno por incrivel que pareça, muitos se referem assim.

Comment: Quando eu tiver 5 pontos, eu tento responder a alguma pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno Bom, tecnicamente, ele é o Stack Overflow original....

Comment: Eu consigo desvincular a conta do StackOverflow pt do StackOverflow en?

Comment: @MBecker as contas não tem "vinculo", é apenas um conta, o que você consegue é remover o vinculo da sua conta StackExchange com uma comunidade especifica, por exemplo hoje participo de cinco sites da rede, mas eu quero sair do site superuser.com, então no meta do site especifico eu acesso o formulário de contato http://meta.superuser.com/contact e seleciono a opção "I need to delete my user profile", preencha o formulário e então é só aguardar a analise.

Comment: Desvincular é o oposto do que deseja. Você esperou ter 5 pontos no SOen para começar responder?

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho 140 pontos (SOen)  e aqui por ter respondido uma pergunta ruim, eu estou preso num loop infinito, já que estou com 4 pontos mas não consigo nem comentar, nem fazer perguntas nem responder perguntas.

Comment: @MBecker é como lhe expliquei SOen e SOpt não tem vinculo algum, o que vc faz no SOen gera pontos nele, o que você fez nele não tem valor no SOpt, os pontos são pelo que vc fez pela comunidade. Veja a explicação: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3851/3635

Comment: Eu resolvi excluir a conta e abri outra só para postar duas respostas que já estavam prontas. Por ironia, uma dessas respostas foi pontuada então resolvi unificar as duas contas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque as comunidades do StackOverflow em [português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), [inglês](http://stackoverflow.com), [espanhol](http://es.stackoverflow.com), [japonês](http://ja.stackoverflow.com) e [russo](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) são comunidades independentes umas das outras. Assim sendo, você tem um nível de pontuação em cada uma delas independente das demais.

Note que há outros sites além de StackOverflows na rede StackExchange. Dentre eles podem ser citados [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), [Mathematics](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com), entre [várias centenas de outros](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name). Em cada um desses sites que você ingressar, a sua pontuação será independente dos demais sites.

O único porém é que se você já for um usuário experiente em alguns sites*, ao entrar em um site novo, você vai começar com 101 pontos de reputação ao invés de apenas 1. Isso serve para remover a maior parte das restrições que valem para usuários novos.

[*] - [Segundo o nosso moderador Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5647/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-migrar-os-pontos-e-medalhas-do-stackoverflow-com#comment21391_5647), o critério exato é ter pelo menos 200 pontos de reputação em um desses.

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3851/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, com certeza. Obrigado.

Comment: Presume-se que alguém que ainda não atingiu 200 pontos ainda não está familiarizado com a ferramenta o suficiente para merecer um *burst* inicial em outro site da rede, o que convenhamos é até pouco. Para a pessoa negativar já é bom ela ter ganho alguma coisa no próprio site, criar *tags* é bom já saber o que pode ou não nessa comunidade específica (o que é até bem pouco), ver votos, filas de análise, essas coisas todas demanda a pessoa ter uma certa destreza na **comunidade específica** que é diferente de outra comunidade.

Comment: Para mim, continua parecendo uma loteria e não uma falta de familiaridade com a ferramenta ou falta de conhecimento.

Comment: @MBecker O que você quer dizer por loteria? Mas, vamos partir do seguinte caso: o fato de você ser um excelente contribuidor no site de [filmes, séries e TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/) ou no de [fé cristã](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) não te torna um excelente contribuidor no StackOverflow, acho que nisso todos concordam. Ocorre que mesmo entre StackOverflows de diferentes línguas, o fato de você ser um excelente contribuidor do site na língua X não o transforma em um excelente contribuidor do site na língua Y. [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Imagine por exemplo se os gringos que não sabem português viessem aqui para começar a postar perguntas e respostas, começassem a fazer edições, fechar questões, etc. Se a reputação fosse compartilhada, isso seria possível. Mas, não há muito sentido devido ao fato de que eles nem falam português. A razão é que eles não tem como contribuir significativamente com este site por causa da diferença linguística, logo a reputação deles de nada vale aqui.

Comment: [continuação 2] O mesmo vale no sentido oposto. Se você for um excelente contribuidor por aqui e não manjar nada ou quase nada de inglês, não vai se dar bem por lá.

Comment: Quando digo loteria, quero dizer em fazer uma boa pergunta ou resposta e ser pontuado continuamente, porque outros usuários irão continuar votando nessa pergunta/resposta. Enquanto você pode ter perguntas e respostas que mesmo boas, não serão nem votadas.

Comment: @MBecker Deixa eu ver se entendi. Se alguém por acaso acha a sua pergunta ou resposta através do google lá no SOen e vota a favor dela, você gostaria de ganhar alguma reputação aqui no SOpt também? É isso?